# Jmeter and identityserver

Tags: asp.net, identityserver3, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to use jmeter for performance testing on an ASP.NET MVC application.
Authentication is based on Identitityserver, i can not configure jmeter, (authentification failed). 
I try to use  windows and password login (via an http authorization manager) without sucess.
In debug, i know that

```html
HttpContext.Current.User
```

is alway empty.

I tried to capture the frames of an authentication with firefox but without result.

If someone has already done this type of tests an help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 HTTP requests in JMeter.
1 to get a token
2 to make a call on your secured API backend

Regarding 1:

I used a clientcredential flow with a reference token. Then in JMeter add the parameters to the request. (client_id, scope, grant_type, client_secret)

You will get a reference token (or jwt token)

Regarding 2:

Add a HTTP Header Manager to your HTTP Request. Then add a header with the name 'Authorization' and value 'Bearer token'

[screenshot of JMeter implementation for OAuth2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd1FD.png)

Comment: To clarify: Add a HTTP Header Manager to your HTTP Request. Then add a header with the name 'Authorization' and value 'Bearer token'. The token is the actual token so you would get something like 'Bearer ea85658ec02278cc97fgrt73aae2f1e8'

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try this

Comment: Added a screenshot of the JMeter config. Will make it a bit more clearer what you need to do. A picture speaks a thousand words:)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Web Driver Sampler for this. You can find more info here https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/

Comment: Thks for your Reply i will try